# Regex matched text between tags is too greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract text from a string, and have trouble with laziness/greediness.

In the example I want the piece of text to match `<b>I want this piece</b>`, so my regex is non-greedy anything between `<b>` and `</b>` as long as it contains 'piece'.

The problem with my regex that the matched text includes `<b>first</b>`.

```
var text = "<b>first</b> <b>I only want this piece</b>";
var regX = /<b>.*?piece.*?<\/b>/;
var matches = text.match(regX);
```

Matched text

```
"<b>first</b> <b>I only want this piece</b>"
```

Desired match

```
"<b>I only want this piece</b>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negated char class instead of the first `.*?`.

```
var regX = /<b>[^<>]*?piece.*?<\/b>/;
```

**Why?**

Because the first `<b>.*?piece` will match the first `<b>` and it continues until it finds the text `piece` and it won't care about the text present in-between. If you use `[^<>]*?`, it would do a lazy match of matching any char but not of `<` or `>`  character zero or more times.

Comment: Thanks, works great! It is not in my question, but how would I implement this for a multiline string?

Comment: `var regX = /<b>[^<>]*?piece[\s\S]*?<\/b>/;`

Answer (score 1):

This would work for excluding any html tags, and might be a little more robust, depending on how predictable your string is:

```
var regX = /<b>(?:(?!<[^>]*>).)*piece.*?<\/b>/
```

If you want to match newline characters, you can use \s\S in addition to the dot (.), e.g. `[.\s\S]`:

```
var regX = /<b>(?:(?!<[^>]*>)[.\s\S])*piece[.\s\S]*?<\/b>/
```